# have jquery not to sort associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, associative-array

How to prevent JavaScript from sorting my associative array? I need the key of my associative array in numbers, or numbers as string, for the array is created dynamically. For some reasons, JS keeps sorting it for me, which causing me problem. BTW, I am using jquery-2.0.3.min.js:

HTML

```
<div id='output'></div>
```

JavaScript

```
//define array
var myUnsortArray={};
myUnsortArray[98+""]='first';
myUnsortArray[99+""]='second';
myUnsortArray[1+""]='third';
myUnsortArray[2+""]='last';

//output array
var a="";
$.each(myUnsortArray,function(key,value){a=a+key+": "+value+"<br/>";});
$("#output").html(a);
```

output:

```
1: third
2: last
98: first
99: second
```

preferred output:

```
98: first
99: second
1: third
2: last
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you planning to use a final amount of strings? Seems like you need to build a big switch/case code (especially if you want to use `final`, which is external to numbering)

Comment: No, I don't plan to use final, but the associative array will be used for some other purpose and having number as the key is essential. Thank you for checking.

Comment: The standard answer to this is: Keys in an "associative array" (object) in JS have no order. Wich is not entirely true but since order is not guaranteed by the spec you should not rely on it. If you want to preserve the order, you should keep a seperate list with the keys in the correct order.

Comment: Use an array instead of object literal if order is important. `{}` is not n array

Comment: Wich is mostly the case, except for <s>numeric</s> uint32 keys; even as strings. This seems to be some internal optimization of the data structure in the actual JS engines.

Comment: @charlietfl, not too sure what you meant. I thought mine example is an array already. Some illustrations would be nice.  Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas, I just hoping the array preserved the order as I created it, which would be dynamically. If I use some random string as the key, the array order would be preserved. But when it is a string number, it sorted for me...Thank you, good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not sorting, that's a specific behavior of Javascript in some browsers, so isn't possible to ensure insertion order.

**Look this code snippet without jQuery's `.each` function:**

```js
//define array
var myUnsortArray = {};
myUnsortArray[98 + ""] = 'first';
myUnsortArray[99 + ""] = 'second';
myUnsortArray[1 + ""] = 'third';
myUnsortArray[2 + ""] = 'last';

//output array
var a = "";
for (key in myUnsortArray) {
  a = a + key + ": " + myUnsortArray[key] + "<br/>";
}

$("#output").html(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="output"></span>
```

See? without jQuery the keys are being sorted.

**The following code snippet shows how to preserve the insertion order using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class:**

```js
var myUnsortMap = new Map();
myUnsortMap.set('98', 'first');
myUnsortMap.set('99', 'second');
myUnsortMap.set('1', 'third');
myUnsortMap.set('2', 'last');

//output array
var a = "";
for (var [key, value] of myUnsortMap) {
  a = a + key + ": " + value + "<br/>";
}

$("#output").html(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="output"></span>
```

See? now it's following the insertion order.

Comment: But should also note that Map doesn't have full browser support

Comment: @charlietfl that's true, however, it's an example to show the alternatives to preserve the insertion order.

Comment: "jQuery is not sorting, that's a specific behavior of javascript in some browsers" No, the problem isn't with the browsers. Objects aren't ordered structures. You're not supposed to use them for things like this.

Comment: If I shouldn't use Objects for things like this, for it is not ordered structures, then I shouldn't use Objects. This is the closest I could find for associative array. Is there any JS ordered structures available, for something like this? I just want to use a simple associative array in JS, and it seems so complicated... thank you for the input

Comment: Both answers are good, but I lean toward this one more, for more in depth explanations, and map allows me to search for the key with value, which similar to wanted associative array.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

What about storing the data differently? Instead of an object consisting of key:value pairs, make it an array consisting of value:position pairs:

```
let unsorted = [];
unsorted.push({value:"first", pos:"98"});
unsorted.push({value:"second", pos:"99"});
unsorted.push({value:"third", pos:"1"});
unsorted.push({value:"last", pos:"2"});

//output array
console.log(unsorted);

var a ="";
$.each(unsorted,function(index, item){
        console.log(item.value);
        a = a + item.pos + ": " + item.value + "<br/>";
    });

$("#output").html(a);

/* Output:
 * 98: first
 * 99: second
 * 1: third
 * 2: last
 */
```

Comment: The OP is not working with Array, just Key-Value pair object.

Comment: I thought I am working with Associative Array, probably I am mistaken.

Comment: @xam javascript doesn't have associative arrays...what you are using is an object literal and they are unordered